# is there any api available for "Dropbox for business" admin

Tags: api, admin, dropbox, dropbox-api

I want to automate the "Dropbox for business" admin console the operation like create user, delete user, reset user password.

Is there an API available for "Dropbox for business" admin?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, check out the [Dropbox for Business API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/business).